# Dynamodb will consider the secondary index also a primary key, before put item into table.?

Tags: insert, amazon-dynamodb, primary-key, secondary-indexes

I have the table named as `message_tbl` in **dynamodb** for messaging system.

For the purpose to fetch all the message items related to particular **conversation_id**, i designed the table like this:

The attributes are:

**Primary Hash key** => `conversation_id`

**Primary Sort key** => `date_time`

**Other attributes** => `sender_id`, `message`

`conversation_id   date_time                sender_id   message
 123456            2016-12-27 06:00:39 pm   10          hai how are you..?
 123456            2016-12-27 06:01:00 pm   11          I am fine
 123456            2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   10          ok
 123456            2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   14          Hai man. How are you.?`

The **last two entries** which is send by `sender_id` => 10 & 14 in same time can have chances to happen right.?
If it happens, will replace the attribute values with the same primary key and the data loss will occur. 
Shall i use an unique random 6 digit string as **secondary local index**, i can get escape from this..?

While put item into db with same conversation_id and date_time can accept if i set **secondary index as sort key (unique random string)**.?
If i am doing wrong, prescribe me to design the table.

Note: I am using PHP Codeigniter MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with DynamoDB if you your `Hash Key` is `conversation_id` and your `Sort Key` is `date_time` and you get those 2 messages:

`conversation_id   date_time                sender_id   message
 123456            2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   10          ok
 123456            2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   14          Hai man. How are you.?`

The last message will overwrite it.

What you could do is have a `message_id`. It's essentially the unique random string you were already thinking as the `Sort Key`. So this would not be overwritten:

`conversation_id   message_id     date_time                sender_id   message
 123456            1123           2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   10          ok
 123456            3213           2016-12-27 06:01:12 pm   14          Hai man`

Then if you want to query by `conversation_id` and sort things by `date_time`, like you had before, you could create a [Local Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).

Comment: Rather than a random value for `message_id`, it should be an incrementing number value for each message in that conversation. Then sorting on it could get them in a meaningful order.

Answer (score 1):

**The Bad News**

The answer to your question is **no**. The secondary index key will not ensure uniqueness on the secondary index's defined key.

The secondary indexes on DynamoDB are intended to act as alternate search paths and not as alternate unique key. You can think of them as non unique indexes from the RDBMS world. They just help in searches by providing alternate organization of the data.

To quote the documentation for Local Secondary Index here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html

> In a DynamoDB table, the combined partition key value and sort key value for each item must be unique. However, in a local secondary index, the sort key value does not need to be unique for a given partition key value. If there are multiple items in the local secondary index that have the same sort key value, a Query operation returns all of the items that have the same partition key value.

And similarly for Global Secondary Indexes here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

> In a DynamoDB table, each key value must be unique. However, the key values in a global secondary index do not need to be unique.

**The Good News**

In order to ensure uniqueness across other fields while performing CRUD operations an approach suggested in this AWS blog can be followed. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/simulating-amazon-dynamodb-unique-constraints-using-transactions/